# Swift compiler hang with array indexing and expressions

Tags: xcode, swift

Xcode 6 Beta 2 (Build 6A216F) will hang if compiling the following Swift code:

```
class A {
    func Something(a:Float[], b:Float[]) {
        var k:Float = a[0]*b[0] + a[0]*b[0] + a[0]*b[0] + a[0]*b[0];
    }
}
```

with default OS X application project settings. I have tested the compiler with

```
var k:Float = a[0]*b[0] + a[0]*b[0] + a[0]*b[0];
```

and the compiler successfully compiles the code. With four a[0]*b[0] adding up together the compiler process (swift) just hangs indefinitely.

So I tried compiling with one a[0]*b[0] term to three a[0]*b[0] terms adding up and I observed that the compiling time grows with more terms in the expression *significantly*.

The question is what is the cause of the compiler to hang?

Comment: I guess the best chance to get an answer is to ask the people who wrote the compiler, especially since the beta us under an non-disclosure agreement at the moment.

Comment: It looks like an obvious bug. Please make a bug report or discuss this on the Apple Developer Forums like @dasblinkenlight said. By the way, I can't compile this from the command line either, so it's a real compiler bug and not some Xcode or Playground bug.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs in an [Apple bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: Yes. I will report that to Apple now. Thanks~